# Applying scale makes object puffed up

Tags: transforms

[image]

[image]

Hello, I am a newbie in blender and I have no idea what is happening.. When I apply scale(ctrl+a > scale), the object becomes puffed up. Can someone please tell me how to fix this problem? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your solidify modifier's thickness is basically the value you enter times the object scale, so when you apply scale that calculation changes and the value needs to change to compensate

Comment: It's a great rule-of-thumb _never_ to scale in object-mode during modelling. If you do, it should make you feel all tingly and want to reach for the apply-button as soon as possible :) .. (Nice boots, BTW)

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed solidify modifier's thickness to 0.01 and it solved the problem! You guys are genius! Thank you!!!!